# Error: Missing \begin{document. Please help!

Tags: errors, luatex, cv, missing

While running my document in TexWorks using LuaLaTeX Typeset, I first got an error saying: `Error: Driver file pgfsys-luatex.def not found`.
After some research, I downloaded the `pgfsys-luatex.def` file and added `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` as per https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/384/

Next, I got the error: `Error: File smartdiagram.sty not found.`
So I downloaded the file from http://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/texmf-dist/tex/latex/smartdiagram/smartdiagram.sty and added it to my working directory.

Finally, I am getting a really annoying error which I can't resolve: `Error: Missing \begin{document}.` I have made sure that the file is saved as UTF-8 as suggested in other threads. Could someone please help me solve this issue? Please have look at the code below:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Twenty Seconds Resume/CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (14/7/16)
%
% Original author:
% Carmine Spagnuolo (cspagnuolo@unisa.it) with major modifications by 
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com) and Harsh (harsh.gadgil@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% The MIT License (see included LICENSE file)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} % a4paper for A4
\usepackage{luatex85}
% Command for printing skill overview bubbles
\newcommand\skills{ 
~
    \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
        \textbf{Data}\\\textbf{Engineering},
        \textbf{Full Stack}\\\textbf{Web Dev},
        \textbf{~~~~~OOP~~~~~~},
        \textbf{Mobile}\\\textbf{Dev},
        \textbf{Machine}\\\textbf{Learning},
        \textbf{Test}\\\textbf{~~Automation~~},
        \textbf{Statistical}\\\textbf{Analysis}
    }
}

% Programming skill bars
\programming{{C $\textbullet$ C++  $\textbullet$ R / 3}, {Java $\textbullet$ SQL $\textbullet$ \large \LaTeX / 3.5}, {HTML5 $\textbullet$ JS $\textbullet$ Python / 5}}

% Projects text
\projects{
\textbf{DecAR} - An augmented reality interior decoration app for Android \\
        \textbf{CIS*6320} - An implementation of the Bicubic interpolation algorithm in C++
        \textbf{CIS*6650} - A comparative statistical study of SVM kernels, and number of hidden layers in ANN, on 5 UCI datasets
        \textbf{CIS*6660} - A data linkage project to integrate Canada's WWI casualties and 1901 Canadian census using an SVM
        \textbf{CIS*6650} - A statistical study of spurious correlations, such as correlating beer production with election outcome
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% If you don't need one or more of the below, just remove the content leaving the command, e.g. \cvnumberphone{}

\cvname{HARSH GADGIL} % Your name
\cvjobtitle{ Data Engineer } % Job
% title/career

\cvlinkedin{/in/hsgadgil}
\cvgithub{opensorceror}
\cvnumberphone{(647) 221 7999} % Phone number
\cvsite{hgadgil.com} % Personal website
\cvmail{harsh.gadgil@gmail.com} % Email address

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makeprofile % Print the sidebar

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Education}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem
        {2015 - 2017}
        {}
        {MSc., Computer Science \textnormal{(GPA: 3.7/4.0)}}
        {\href{http://www.uoguelph.ca/}{University of Guelph, Canada}}
        {}
        {}
    \twentyitem
        {2009 - 2013}
        {}
        {BEng., Computer Engineering \textnormal{(GPA: 4.0/4.0)}}
        {\href{http://www.unipune.ac.in/}{University of Pune, India}}
        {}
        {}
    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<organization>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

\section{Research}
\begin{twenty}
    \twentyitem
        {2015 - 2017}
        {}
        {MSc. Candidate, Graduate Research Assistant}
        {\href{http://www.uoguelph.ca/}{University of Guelph}}
        {}
        {
        \textbf{Thesis}: Data Integration from Multiple Historical Sources to Study Canadian Casualties of WWI
        {\begin{itemize}
        \item Proposed a scalable stepwise deterministic method to reliably integrate datasets without labeled data. The method performs comparably with a method that incorporates a Support Vector Machine
        \item Constructed a rich longitudinal dataset to enable comphrehensive time-series analyses about WWI Canadian society and military
        \item \textbf{Tools}: R, Python, scikit-learn, BeautifulSoup, pandas, matplotlib \vspace{2mm}
        \end{itemize}}
        }
\end{twenty}

\section{Publications}
L. Antonie, H. Gadgil, G. Grewal, and K. Inwood, “Historical Data Integration - A Study of WWI Canadian Soldiers,” in 2016 IEEE 16th International Conference on Data Mining Workshops (ICDMW), pp. 186-193, IEEE, 2016. \vspace{2mm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
\twentyitem
        {April 2017 -}
        {Present}
        {Data Engineer}
        {\href{http://www.bell.ca/}{Bell}}
        {}
        {\begin{itemize}
        \item Currently involved in building a realtime data ingestion pipeline on a Kafka cluster using Spark Streaming, to detect SMS spammers on Bell's network in realtime
        \end{itemize}}
        \\
    \twentyitem
        {Sep 2015 -}
        {May 2016}
        {Co-founder \& Full Stack Developer}
        {\href{http://www.localxchange.ca/}{LocalXChange Inc.}}
        {}
        {
        {\begin{itemize}
        \item In a team of 2, raised \$8,000 in funding from The Hub incubator at the University of Guelph, to develop a prototype hyperlocal content platform, aimed at delivering local news and events from community organizations to local users in realtime (i.e., hyperlocal)
        \item In a team of 3, built hybrid mobile \& web apps with Ionic, Angular.js and MongoDB, surpassing 1,000 users within a month since launch
        \item Met with city officials, including the Mayor of Guelph, and university officials to discuss marketing \& business strategies for the platform 
    \end{itemize}}
        }
    \\   
    \twentyitem
        {Sep 2015 -}
        {Dec 2016}
        {Graduate Teaching Assistant}
        {\href{http://www.uoguelph.ca}{University of Guelph}}
        {}
        {
        {\begin{itemize}
        \item TA for CIS*2430 (OOP), CIS*4150 (Software Reliability \& Testing) and CIS*3530 (Database Systems \& Concepts) courses
    \end{itemize}}
        }
     \\
     \twentyitem
        {Dec 2013 -}
        {Apr 2015}
        {Test Automation Engineer}
        {\href{http://www.synechron.com/}{Synechron}}
        {}
        {
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Developed a \textit{Keyword Driven} and \textit{Behavior Driven} test automation framework for \href{https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/dynamics/crm.aspx}{Microsoft Dynamics CRM}. Wrote an efficient recursive function to search multi-level frames, reducing development time by approximately two weeks. Won SPOT award {\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{img/trophy.png}}

        \textit{My work opened up a new position in the organization, enabling it to earn additional revenue of \$3,500 per month (estimated)}
        \item Demonstrated by proof of concept that rewriting a test automation framework for \href{https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/dynamics/erp-ax-overview.aspx}{Microsoft Dynamics AX}, using an open source library (White) instead of a proprietary one (Coded UI), would enable the team to save \$4,000 annually by downgrading the prevailing edition of Microsoft Visual Studio from \textit{Premium} to \textit{Professional}
    \end{itemize}
        }

    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The first error I get is `twentysecondcv class` not found. Where can we get this class from?

Comment: Thank you. 
Please have a look at the complete project here: https://github.com/opensorceror/Data-Engineer-Resume-LaTeX

Comment: The template is available in version 1.1 since january this year. With it, it works fine. By the way, where is the download link from the  original code? It would have helped people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are two versions of this resume class available.

When I try to compile your code with class `\ProvidesClass{twentysecondcv}[2015/02/28 CV class]` I get the error `Missing \begin{document}` too.

It seems you are calling an older version ...

With the class you gave the link to the code compiles without error!
Please make sure that you have your TeX file and the correct class in one directory ... On my computer I have

[image]

Do not forget to copy the directory `fonts` ...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure if I understand you correctly.
I have taken the exact files from the Github link, and only modified the sections specified in my question. The Tex and class files are also in the same directory. But I still get this same error.

Comment: Here by the way the link to the tempalte: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv